# eclipse - how to get count of word being searched?

Tags: eclipse, find

I am surprised to see that I am not able to check the number of occurrences of word I am trying to find. For just this one feature I need to switch to Notepad++ to do a find and check the count.

I tried to google, and search most of the locations on internet as far as I know, but didn't find anything. Have anyone encountered this issue? Any workaround? Or am I missing some basic hidden config in the eclipse world of preferences?

Note: I am aware of the highlight all feature, but I am interested in count of a word, e.g. Number of occurrences of word `MyArray`.

Also, no such feature in console output as well.

Answer (score 5):

Using the 'File' tab of the 'Search' menu option to do a search produces results in the Search view which have occurrence counts.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful for searching contents of files under the project. But, how to count the occurrances of a word in the console output window? I can do a normal find (Ctrl + F), but don't see how to get the count here.

Comment: I don't know of anything to do that in the console window

Comment: What I did, coming here, based on this suggestion: Copy the entire console into a dummyfile.txt, and then use the Ctrl-H search.

Answer (score 5):

Highlight any string and hit Ctrl+Shift+U. It will give the occurrence in the Search window.

Comment: I just get the message '<no occurence searches available on selection>'

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+U doesn't do anything for me - nothing happens. The other solution with the 'File'-Tab did it for me though.

Answer (score 5):

Find and Replace the same word so it will not be changed, and then press "Replace All". On the bottom of the search window you will see "xxx matches replaced". You also can Replace All and then revert the changes, when you missed it to set the "Replace with" field.

Comment: What do you mean "...so it will not be changed"?

Comment: He means: search 'foo', replace it with 'foo' => nothing changes but the occurences are counted